# How do I call a C function from a library installed with `apt install` using ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes, python-bindings, libunistring

I am trying to call [`ulc_width_linebreaks` from `unilbrk`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=lib/unilbrk/ulc-width-linebreaks.c;h=f051b877a7c2d45c413b3e8dda32b65526ad1d04;hb=HEAD#l44) from [GNU's `libunistring`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/) (a C function) on my Python strings using the [`ctypes` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html). `libunistring` is [available on Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libunistring&searchon=names&suite=groovy&section=all), and I've installed it with `sudo apt install libunistring2 libunistring-dev`. I opened a new terminal window and tried to import the library from Python. I tried the following but all returned `None`:

```py
ctypes.util.find_library("libunistring")
ctypes.util.find_library("libunistring2")
ctypes.util.find_library("unilbrk")
ctypes.util.find_library("unilbrk.h")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the install location of the library, which you can do with

```
$ dpkg -L libunistring2
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2.1.0
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libunistring2
/usr/share/doc/libunistring2/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libunistring2/copyright
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2
```

and then load it and call it like this

```py
import ctypes
from pathlib import Path

libunistring_path = Path("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so")
libunistring = ctypes.CDLL(libunistring_path)
libunistring.ulc_width_linebreaks.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p]

libunistring.ulc_width_linebreaks("your args here")
```